# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Both API and database is running in docker containers. I'm using postgresql DB and entity framework code first approach for database. I can do add-migration but when I run remove-migration I get the error which is weird. The exception details are shown below:

```
Entity Framework Core 5.0.11 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Moodys.Ag.Ceres.Data MigrationsHistoryTable=public.__EFMigrationsHistory using snake-case naming  (culture=)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.RemoveMigration(String projectDir, String rootNamespace, Boolean force, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.RemoveMigration(String contextType, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigrationImpl(String contextType, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
No such host is known.
```

Comment: please also add commands which you use to add and remove migrations.

Comment: @Ali Zeinali: "remove-migration" is the command used in Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution which is using `remove-migration -Force` command. It removes the last migration file and reverts the model snapshot. But it has warning which is still related to error I posted in the question. The issue is that remove-migration somehow not able to connect to database from the given host and throwing "No such host is known".

I'm still looking for the solution that doesn't need to use -Force. So if someone finds the solution of this please post it here.

Thank you!